# Overwrite getter to act differently depending on where it was called in template o not. Django

Tags: python, django

Is it posible object to know if it getter called in template or not?
Check for same global variables or any ideas? 
I wanna Moddel to give field attributes wrapped in div when it is called in template.

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution. A better idea would be a separate model method, or a template filter.

Comment: Your model shouldn't worry about display. Models are about data. Views and templates determine display.

Comment: I want to write decorator, that gives ability to modify you models in website pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It is not possible. You could write a custom template tag like {% divwrapper model.attr %} or you could write a model method like "html_dump_all_attrs" that returned something. But no, your solution won't work.